# cycles rendering is too dark

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This problem has troubled me for a long time. When I render the object under cycles, it will appear black and dark. No matter whether I adjust the light source or HDRI, I can't make it have a uniform color.But I once created an object that didn't turn black, and I forgot how I did it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to have overlapping particles. Maybe that's some sort of z-fighting.

Comment: u are right! thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object has two vertex groups, 1 and 2 and you use them for distributing the particles and adjusted the *Number* of particles to the amount of vertices in the according groups.

However, group 1 has 6304 vertices, but 3143 of them are duplicates. Which means, there will be two spheres instanced in the same location, which results in Z-fighting as @MartynasŽiemys already suspected.

Group 2 is even worse, it has 15812 vertices, and while in some locations are double vertices, there are even somtimes 8(!) vertices in the same place.

So to ged rid of all the duplicates go into *Edit Mode*, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*. A message at the bottom will tell you that 15785 vertices were removed.

[image: merge by distance]

Now you can check the groups how many vertices they have left and set the values in the particle systems to these numbers, group 1 has now 3161 and group 2 has 3170 vertices.

[image: group vertices]

Merging the vertices alone will not make the spheres look correct, because the number of particles matching the old numbers will now lead to doubled spheres even though the duplicate vertices are deleted. But when you use the new lower values in the particle systems, there are no longer dark shadows caused by Z-fighting:

[image: new particle systems]

Comment: thank  u so much 

Comment: @DanielRadin You're welcome. If this solved your problem please consider accepting this answer, read more about it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: thanks! got it!